# How can I get text's heigth from pdf's transformation matrix?

Tags: pdf, text, matrix, height, adobe-illustrator

I am making a pdf parser and I have a problem when I am trying to read the transformation matrix (Tm) of a text.

For example, when I have a horizontal text, the transformation matrix looks like this:
 "71.9871 0 0 73.5 178.668 522.2227 Tm"
 which means that the text's height is the d parameter (73.5), the ratio of each character is a/d (71.9871/73.5) and it has to be translated to the point (178.668 522.2227).

If I rotate this text, then the transformation matrix looks like this:
"63.1614 -34.5367 35.2625 64.4888 181.8616 575.8494 Tm"

How can I get the height of the text, which is 73.5?

If I export the same file as an svg file I get this matrix:
"0.8593 0.4699 -0.4798 0.8774 181.8616 266.0405" 
and that the height of the text is 73.5. (I have noticed that if i divide the d parameter of my rotated text with the text's height (73.5) I get the d parameter of the svg matrix (0.8774), but agian, how can I know the text's height?).

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you are aware that (at least!) two matrices and three scalars are involved here? You have the current transformation matrix, the text matrix, the font size, the horizontal scaling, and the page user unit setting.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment, you actually have a multitude of matrices and scalars to deal with, at least the current transformation matrix, the text matrix, the font size, the horizontal scaling, and the page user unit setting. Of course, though, you can combine all these into one matrix.

Thus, let's assume the matrix you have is this combined one.

To determine the factors by which the font is stretched from its size 1 default state, you could simply apply that matrix to a vertical and a horizontal line segment of length 1, e.g. [0, 0, 1] to [1, 0, 1] and [0, 0, 1] to [0, !, 1], and then calculate the lengths of the resulting line segments.

**PS** Doing some minor linear algebra, you will see that for a matrix

```
a b 0
c d 0
e f 1
```

this amounts to a **horizontal font extent of `sqrt(a² + b²)`** and a **vertical font extent (the *height*) of `sqrt(c² + d²)`**.